# Creating a campaign to track links

Tags: google-analytics

I'm new to google analytics and I'm a little confused on how to get an unpaid campaign up and runnning. I'm making the campaign in order to track links to a page from different sources (website buttons, emails, newsletters, etc.). What I'm trying to do is set something up in GA so that I can track how people are getting to a specified page. I've been reading this as well:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en&ref_topic=1032998

Do I have to create the campaign in google analytics (and if so where) or do I just apply the appropriate campaign/tracking tags to the links I need tracked and it automatically creates it?  Also, how would this work with emails?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you will build the campaign tracking URL in [URL Builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en) and put those links in your email, newsletter, etc. Once visitors start to click the links via the email, a campaign will be created under Acquisition > Campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need create campaigns at Google Analytics: when you tagged campaign manually or at URL builder, your campaign data(source name,campaigh name and others) will be categorized by Google Analytics automatically.

GA parses tags at your links and save data about you campaigns.